# Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS: How to show scancodes?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, keycodes

I want to show my scancodes, because Ubuntu doesn't map my keyboard correctly. (Multiple keys (<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and <kbd>Strg</kbd>) have the same keycode and act like <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>).

Windows 10 maps my keyboard correctly...

```
showkey --scancodes
```

and

```
sudo evtest
```

doesn't work on my system.

```
xev
```

shows only the keycodes.

How do I display the scancodes of the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showkey --scancodes` works if you run it from a console window, which you can open via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. (Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to close it afterwards.)

Comment: On my system (German Ubuntu) comes the message "Konnte keinen Dateideskriptor finden, der auf die Konsole verweist" -> in english "Could not find file descriptor that refers to the console"... So it doesn't works on my system ...

Comment: @C.D.Miksche: If I try the command from gnome-terminal, I get precisely that error message, but if I open a console window as mentioned above, and log in there, the command works for me.

Comment: Thank you. The command worked in the console. Unfortunatly the keys have the same scancode and keycode ....