# Ubuntu: show what keys are pressed in real-time

Tags: keyboard

I am looking for a tool that tells what keys (including Alt, Shift, Ctrl, etc) are pressed now. Need it to do a health-check on a possibly faulty keyboard.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/810044/ubuntu-16-04-01-lts-how-to-show-scancodes

Comment: `xev` would be what I'd use

Comment: Since this question is closed, see also: [Unix & Linux: How to detect global key presses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120199/how-to-detect-global-key-presses/683257). I put [my summary of findings here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683257/114401).

Answer (score 14):

Install `keymon`. It's in the Universe repository and run it using `key-mon` (not `keymon`!).

[man keymon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/key-mon.1.html) has this:

> Keymon - Keyboard and mouse monitor window for GTK.

Do read `man keymon` for all the options available.

You should also right-click on it to check that the settings are appropriate for you.

And if you don't like the default location, drag it to a more suitable position on your screen.

An alternative is `screenkey`, also in the Universe repository. A feature of screenkey is that it's interface only when you type something and disappears after a few seconds if the keyboard is inactive. However, unlike keymon, screenkey doesn't register mouse clicks.

There's [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raw0OtUej6k) on both `keymon` and `screenkey`. The video's in German but still is easy to follow.

Comment: A search for `keymon` of `key-mon` currently returns no results from the Universe. You might need to expand your answer.

Comment: `screenkey` works great :3

Answer (score 13):

To test a possibly faulty keyboard it's best to go as low-level as possible. One of the easiest ways to do this without diving into kernel space is to work almost directly with `/dev/input/event*` device files. Namely, you can use `evtest` to see all the keyboard input. If you run it in grabbing mode, this will let you intercept *everything*—even [Magic SysRq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) combos (funnily, even [SAK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key))!

Here's how I'd go about it. First, get a list of input devices by running `sudo evtest`:

```
$ sudo evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:      Power Button
/dev/input/event1:      Power Button
/dev/input/event2:      PC Speaker
/dev/input/event3:      Video Bus
/dev/input/event4:      HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event5:      HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event6:      HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event7:      HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/dev/input/event8:      HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10
/dev/input/event9:      HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
/dev/input/event10:     HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
/dev/input/event11:     HDA Intel PCH Line
/dev/input/event12:     HDA Intel PCH Line Out
/dev/input/event13:     HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
/dev/input/event14:     HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event15:     HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event16:     HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event17:     ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse
/dev/input/event18:     AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Select the device event number [0-18]:
```

Don't choose anything here yet: just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This run of `evtest` was in a simple non-grabbing mode, which won't let you intercept everything. But you now know the device file you need (in my case given above, it's `/dev/input/event18`).

Now you can actually run `evtest` in grabbing mode, using the `--grab` option, so that it intercepts all events from the keyboard—including the release of <kbd>Return</kbd> after you submit your command to the shell, subsequent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, Magic SysRq, VT switch shortcuts etc.. To avoid being locked out of the system, we'll set up a timeout for `evtest`.

```
sudo su -c 'sleep 1; timeout -k5 10 evtest --grab /dev/input/event18'
```

This command does the following:

- Waits 1 second so that you can release <kbd>Return</kbd> before the keyboard is grabbed (otherwise you'll get autorepeats rapidly scrolling the console)
- Starts `evtest` in grabbing mode on my keyboard's device file (replace it with yours).
- `evtest` is run with a timeout of 10 seconds, and additional grace period of 5 seconds in (unlikely) case it hangs, after which it's killed by `SIGKILL`, hopefully returning keyboard control to you.
- `sudo` is wrapped around the whole command instead of only `evtest` to make sure that you enter the password (if needed) *before* `sleep 1`, otherwise this sleep will be useless

During the timeout of 10 seconds (which you can, of course, change to something that suits you better) you can press anything on your keyboard—aside maybe from <kbd>Fn</kbd>-driven keys, which might work in a nonstandard way—and see what it inputs.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do `sudo sleep 1` to prevent the password issue?

Comment: @OctaviaTogami indeed; I've edited the answer with an even simpler approach.

Comment: Install with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install evtest`.

Comment: Upvoted. This works great! See also the `sudo showkey` [answer here](https://superuser.com/a/248568/425838), and [my comment underneath it with a summary here](https://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux#comment2606625_248568).

Comment: @GabrielStaples `showkey` is higher-level than `evtest`. It works with `/dev/console` instead of the actual keyboard. Thus, not only can't `showkey` intercept Magic-SysRq et al., it doesn't even let you choose the keyboard to check, instead accepting input from all keyboards attached to its console.

Comment: Instead of running `sudo evtest` once just to see which event number the keyboard is, you can obtain that path immediately, matching the word `keyboard`, like this: `path_to_keyboard="/dev/input/$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -B 1 -A 10 -i keyboard | awk 'NR==6 {print $4}')"`. That allows you to run this: `path_to_keyboard="/dev/input/$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -B 1 -A 10 -i keyboard | awk 'NR==6 {print $4}')"; sudo su -c "sleep 1; timeout -k5 10 evtest --grab $path_to_keyboard"`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples there may be multiple keyboards, and some single multimedia keyboards have multiple HID presentations. My _Logitech G213 Prodigy_ is an example.

Comment: @Ruslan, I see. I suppose you have to be very specific if trying to script something. Replace the grep for `keyboard` above with a grep for `"AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"`, then it would work, no?

Comment: @GabrielStaples first, the output in the answer was done when I had a PS/2 connection for the keyboard. This string will match it indeed. But now with USB connection I have two entries with the same name, `Logitech Gaming Keyboard G213`. Only one of them reports the normal keys like alphanumeric, functional etc.

Comment: Got it; makes sense. In case you're interested, I put a summary of my findings [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683257/114401), and referenced your answer.

Comment: Works great! I tested this with two keyboards, and two keyboards can be identified.

Comment: Would have liked to try this, but evtest only listed 14 devices, and none are my keyboard.  :)  Oh well.  Still a useful command to know.

Comment: @odigity this is odd. What X driver are you using for your keyboard? Does it use a device not from `/dev/input/*`? And what interface is the keyboard connected to?

Comment: @Rusian - I was just coming back here to delete my comment because I figured out that "Telink Wireless Receiver" was my keyboard.  (model is X9 X9RFERGOKEY, amazon product B08G58HFTM - uses a wireless dongle)

Answer (score 10):

`xev` is also an option. Install it, if it is not already installed, with:

```
sudo apt install xev
```

Then just run:

```
xev
```

Make sure that the small, white window that opens is selected and press any key to see details about it.

To limit `xev`'s rather verbose output, so that it only shows the keys that you press, you can pass its output to `awk`:

```bash
xev | awk /keysym/'{sub(/\),/,""); print $7}'
```

In any case, note that `xev` registers two events for every key that you press, one for pressing the key and one for releasing it.

Answer (score 9):

There is a website https://www.keyboardtester.com/ which lets you see which keys you have pressed, and it shows the keyboard layout. Also, there is a package called `xkeycaps` which can be used.  Moving the mouse over a key describes the keysyms and modifiers that that key generates

There are more sites available like

- http://en.key-test.ru/
- http://keyboardchecker.com/
- https://keyboardtester.co/keyboard-tester.html
- https://www.onlinemictest.com/keyboard-test/

Comment: The site shows me a QWERTY keyboard, while I use an AZERTY one.

Comment: And it's broken for my en-gb QWERTY. Zero effort has gone into localisation there.