# Figure out non working keys

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

Is there a way in Ubuntu to know which keys on the keyboard aren't working?

Except for pressing every key for figuring it out.

Comment: Ubuntu only knows if a key is *reporting* being pressed or not. It has no idea if the key is *actually* being pressed or not.

Comment: I have answered a similar question here https://askubuntu.com/a/1197656/890892